# How to develop Apex in Professional Edition 30 days trial?

Tags: sandbox, professional-edition, production

I want to do some practice with deploying changesets. I have sighed up for 30 days trial of Professional edition here http://www.salesforce.com/ap/crm/editions-pricing.jsp
I created 1 developer sandbox, but neither in production or sandbox I cannot create apex class. On my profile or permission set there is no permission 'Author Apex' at all. In developer console 'Create new -> Apex class and trigger' buttons are disabled. Is there any way to develop apex for free somewhere else than developer edition?

Comment: try Enterprise Edition -- it has force.com platform, so you can practise via changeset deployment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Professional Edition does not include Apex. You can get a free Developer Org (or more than one) at the [Salesforce Developer Site](https://developer.salesforce.com/gettingstarted) where you have full access to Apex, VisualForce and most other features like Workflow, Process Builder and case management.

Alternatively sign up for Enterprise or Performance edition on a 30 day trial as that will include Apex and Visualforce.

To deploy Apex code into Professional Edition you would need to use packages or AppExchange Apps rather than create in a Developer Org and deploy.

Deploying Apex via Change Sets is not intrinsically different than deploying other components apart from the need to have Test Classes with Code Coverage above 75%

Comment: Professional Edition does not include Apex development absolutely or only in trial version?

Comment: Professional Edition will never include Apex development, it is often quite challenging to implement because of this. The only option is to develop the code and deliver as an unmanaged or managed package.

Comment: WHen deploying package from AppExchange I get an error: "Installing this package requires the following feature and its associated permissions: Apex Classes".

Comment: On the details of any AppExchange Package it will say which editions it supports so only packages marked for Professional Edition will be able to be installed.

Comment: I installed it not from AppExchange, but directly with install url. Just a managed package, created in dev org

Comment: Vladyslav I would raise that as a new question so that you can get an answer for what needs to be done to make a managed package work with the Professional Edition.

Comment: I cannot use APEX, I have a developer version(Entreprise trial is not possible anymore). If i go to AppExchange which package should execute?